# What does the mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given mean?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this PHP page:

```
<?php

//$_GET['invite'] = kNdqyJTjcf;

$code = mysqli_real_escape_string ($dbc, $_GET['invite']);

$q = "SELECT invite_id FROM signups_invited WHERE (code = '$code') LIMIT 1";
$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

if (mysqli_num_rows($r) == 1) {
    echo 'Verified';
} else {
    echo 'That is not valid. Sorry.';
}

?>
```

This is returning the error `Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given`.

Any idea why?

Comment: what is $dbc, where it is define?

Comment: @Book Of Zeus and Pekka Ah... thanks. I am pretty stupid. You should put an answer so I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to define: `$dbc` before

```
 $code = mysqli_real_escape_string ($dbc, $_GET['invite']);
```

ex:

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
```

Answer (score 7):

It's helpful to learn to read error messages and try to figure out what might be causing them. :)

This one tells you **exactly** what the problem is, and where to start looking.

```
Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given.
```

The message tells you that the problem is `parameter 1` provided to `mysqli_error`, and that it was `null` when `mysqli_error` expected it to be a `mysqli`.

So look at the first parameter you're providing to `mysqli_error`, and you'll see it's `$dbc`. You know now that the problem is that `$dbc` is null when the call to `mysqli_error()` is made. So look at how it is that `$dbc` can be `null`. Oh, right - you didn't declare it and assign anything to it, because the first place it's used in the code is here:

```
$code = mysqli_real_escape_string ($dbc, $_GET['invite']);
```

and it's being used as if it's already something other than `null`. Since this is at the start of your code, the problem is that you forgot to declare and initialize it by connecting to the database. Problem solved. :)

Answer (score 2):

undefined variable `$dbc` in `mysqli_error($dbc)`. you need to put your connection obj here.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're getting this error because you need to do:

```
global $mysqli;
```

in whatever function you're in.

Answer (score -1):

Don't confuse `mysql_connect();` with `mysqli_connect();`

Try to change as follows

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("yourhost", "username", "password", "database-name");
```

Then if it's connected pass your query with

```
mysqli_query($conn, "your query string");
```

Now it works fine!