# Register Form not working - php errors

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a register form for my site
The form works, but when i submit, it gives theses errors:

```
    Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in /home/toonbox/public_html/Rework/register.php on line 28

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in /home/toonbox/public_html/Rework/register.php on line 29

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in /home/toonbox/public_html/Rework/register.php on line 30

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in /home/toonbox/public_html/Rework/register.php on line 31
Error: Please fill in the form!
Notice: Undefined variable: row in /home/toonbox/public_html/Rework/register.php on line 44

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in /home/toonbox/public_html/Rework/register.php on line 48
Unable to access the table!
```

Heres the code

```
    <?php
//REGISTER.PHP
//By Sheriff Reggie.

//temp
//used to check the errors in the script
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

session_start(); //starts php session

require "register.inc.php"; //include the config file

if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
   header("location: play.php");
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

//variables
$userPOST = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
$passPOST = $_POST['pass'];
//$passchk = $_POST['pass']; //to do soon
$emailPOST = $_POST['email'];
$keyPOST = $_POST['key'];

$user = mysqli_real_escape_string($userPOST, $dbcon);
$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($passPOST, $dbcon);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($emailPOST, $dbcon);
$key = mysqli_real_escape_string($keyPOST, $dbcon);

if($user == "" || $pass = "" || $email = "" || $key = "")
{
  echo "Error: Please fill in the form!";
}

else
{
     $row = mysqli_num_rows($query);
     $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$user'",$dbcon) or die ("Unable to access the table!");

    }
    if($row == 1)
      echo "User already exist. Please choose a different username!";
    {
    //verify key is valid
    $querykey = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE keys = '$key'", $dbcon) or die ("Unable to access the table!");
    $rowkey = mysqli_num_rows($querykey);
    if(!$rowkey == 1)
      echo "Key isn't valid. Try again!";
    }
    if($rowkey == 1)
    {
     $reg = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (id, username, password, email, key) VALUES (null, '$user', '$pass', '$email', '$key'),$dbcon")  or die ("Cannot register. An error occured!");
     echo "Sucessfully registered!";
   }
}
?>
<html>
<div align="center">
<!-- Yes joe, ill add style later. Lemme just test this !-->
<form name="register" method="post" action="register.php">
<input name="user" type="text" id="username" value="Your Username"><br><br>
<input name="pass" type="password" id="pass" value="Your Password"><br><br>
<input name="email" type="text" id="email"  value="Your E-mail"><br><br>
<input name="key" type="text" id="key"  value="An Valid Alpha Key"><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">
</div>
</form>
</html>
```

I tried and tried and couldnt find the error in the code.
I'm really desperate to find the source of it.
Any way to fix this?

EDIT 1:
I think i found out why.
I forgot to change the mysql to mysqli in my include file
Thanks anyways :)

Comment: Did you read the error messages? They tell you *exactly* what is wrong.

Comment: [Do a search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457191/what-does-the-mysqli-error-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli-null-given-mean)

Comment: You've got that the other way around `$user = mysqli_real_escape_string($userPOST, $dbcon);` Use `$user=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon,$_POST['userPOST']);` and do the rest for the others. Or `$user = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon,$userPOST);` Plus, `mysql_query` to `mysqli_query`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, You have used `$query = mysql_query` instead of `mysqli_` and `mysqli_num_rows` come after the select `$query`

**Syntax:** `mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )`

Corrected syntax:

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $userPOST);

$query = mysqli_query($dbcon, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$user'") or die ("Unable to access the table!");

$row = mysqli_num_rows($query);
```