# "mysqli_xxx() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given" errors since server change

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

For starters, please know that I have been working on this issue for either 4 or 5 days.  I've searched here, on Google, looked at syntax and compared it with PHP.net and w3schools.com and I can't find an answer.  This post is a last resort not a first effort.

The problem is that I had a number of search pages that were all working fine on my databases.  My web hosting company has been having all kinds of issues and moved my stuff to another server.  Now as soon as I pull up one of the search pages I get a host of errors that I never got before.  I'm now on PHP 5.3.28.  I don't know, but suspect that the other server might have been an earlier version.

In all the things I've tried I've limited it down, I believe, to the same code in each page. The following 'If else' code used to stop the PHP as soon as it found that the search string was found to be empty and post a message.  Now, all the pages print the message but the code apparently continues now for some unknown reason and in the process generates a bunch of error messages.  If I enter something in the search box the correct results come up right and all the error messages disappear and don't come back until I do a fresh reload of the page.  Anyone have an idea why this doesn't stop where it should anymore?

```
<?php

// conversion of form input to string
$ser = $_POST['searchstring'];

if (empty ($ser)){
    echo "<center>" . 'Please enter something to search.' . "</center>";
}
else
```

Here is a list of the error messages that are only there on the first load of the page.

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/jimray/public_html/movies/actors.php on line 52
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /home/jimray/public_html/movies/actors.php on line 53
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/jimray/public_html/movies/actors.php on line 57
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /home/jimray/public_html/movies/actors.php on line 58
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /home/jimray/public_html/movies/actors.php on line 70
Warning: mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/jimray/public_html/movies/actors.php on line 104
```

I believe they are all due to the empty search string.

I can list those lines if need be.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: this message means that db connection is not established, there are TONS of pages and manuals, you need 2-3 hours to read php/mysqli documentation and 2-3 hours to read your code to find root cause

Comment: Sidenote : [don't use](http://www.w3fools.com/) W3S****ls.

Comment: From looking at the errors it is that a null is passed to the respective functions when it is not allowed.  Chances are that is because as @Lashane said a db connection was not established properly.  This may be due to a difference in php version (different syntax) or mysqli not being installed on the new server.  Either way, since your host moved your server, they should ensure it suits your needs just as the old one did.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7457313/2864740

Comment: Thanks for your help folks but I've spent the better part of the day trying to solve this on my own.  The one unanswerable thing I haven't solved is that I pasted the above code into a new php document and populated $ser manually.  It works fine and stops if the string is empty.  I just can't figure out why it won't work after the HTML form, which it did before.  As for the error messages I already knew it was caused by the failure of the if/else statement.  Where there are still issues the hosting company is upgrading me and hopefully that will solve this mystery.

Comment: It doesn't look like anything is wrong with the if/else statement.  All of the error messages are due to the first parameter being NULL on the function calls for the lines 52, 53, 57, 58, 70 and 104.  For these function calls, that parameter is what contains your database connection string.  Look on those lines and run a search for where that variable is defined (if at all).  Then along the way to line 52 from where it is defined see where it loses its value.  Note there is a chance that variable may be defined in another file depending on how everything is setup.

Answer (score 0):

To all who offered their help, my thanks.

Believe it or not, it was a web server issue.  I've been having trouble for about 6 weeks.  They transferred me from the server I had to a faster server and that's when the PHP trouble began.  Last night, because of continued slow loads, page timeouts and internal server errors they gave me a free major upgrade to a business grade server.  This morning, all the pages are working fine again.

This company has been great for the three years I have been with them until this glitch about 6 weeks ago.  But, they've done me right now and I'll be staying with them.  Again, thanks for everyone's efforts.