# PHP MySQL SSL certificate

Tags: php, mysql, ssl, mysqli

I have a vb.net software and I shall use php code on my website to make a user for the customer. I have tried many codes but I always get the same error:

> Warning:
>
> mysqli_ssl_set() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in
>   xxxxxxxxxxx/makeuser/insert.php on line 12 Warning: mysqli::mysqli():
>   (HY000/2002):

The php code also needs certificate so where shall I store the certificate. Shall I store them in my webserver? I understand that I can store the certificate in my webserver but is it safe?

When I shall execute my SQL script I am doing like this:

```
$sql = $conn->prepare ("CREATE DATABASE '$_POST[group]' /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */;");
```

I also get an error on the execute process. If I use `$ssl` instead of `$conn` I don't get the error. Is that correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the mysqli\_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457191/what-does-the-mysqli-error-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli-null-given-mean)

Comment: I think that creating databases/tables should be a rare event. It has lots of repercussions on performance

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And [How to create a Minimal, Complete and veriiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Whoa.

First things first NEVER use `$_POST` directly in SQL. This is dangerous. I could post `"; drop all databases"` and it would run.

Next, the query, that error is because your MySQL query failed, either syntax error, or connection. How are you creating the `$conn` object? Should be

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($host...
```

if you are not connected to your MySQL server, that's your problem, read the php docs regarding `mysqli`.

SSL certificate - are you talking about your MySQL connection, or the web server itself? It should not be placed somewhere accessible to the web, no, it is usually installed onto the server and configured with your web server software (Apache/nginx)